# Do not normalize docker container names in traefik rules

Tags: docker, traefik

I want to use Traefik v2.5 as a local reverse proxy to access all docker containers of my local daemon using a domain of pattern `http://container_name.localhost` in my browser.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=true"
      - "--providers.docker.defaultrule=Host(`{{ .Name }}.localhost `)"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
```

Then I started the container and a simple web server to see if it worked:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker run -d --name my_nginx nginx
```

Then, I was able to access the web server at http://my-nginx.docker.localhost/. However, the name of the docker container uses underscores and not hyphens. This makes it very confusing if you just want to access one of your containers in the browser. Therefore, I want to access the container using http://my_nginx.localhost/. Is there a way to disable the normalization of the traefik rule?

I am aware that one normally uses hyphens in URLs, but docker just wants to have it's underscores, and this is just my local dev environment. I also do not want to add a traefik label manually, e.g.

```
traefik.http.routers.my_nginx.rule==Host(`my_nginx.localhost`)
```

whenever I start a simple dev container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the [docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/file/#go-templating), and it's written that you have sprig functions available in the go template snippets.

Therefore, you can leverage go template + sprigs [string functions](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) to replace the hyphen with underscores.

```
Host(`{{ .Name | replace "-" "_" }}.localhost `)
```